Slow chunk file Upload Speeds with Nginx and Node.js Despite Low Server Resource Usage

I've been struggling with slow upload speeds when handling file
uploads through an Nginx reverse proxy to a Node.js (Express)
backend. Despite the server having plenty of resources available (low
CPU and memory usage), each chunk upload (5 MB in size) takes
approximately 1.5 minutes to complete.
My Setup:
Server Configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Server Specs: 8 GB RAM, 8-core CPU, SSD storage
Location: Hetzner Cloud (us-east)

Nginx Configuration:
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
 }

http {
    client_max_body_size 200M;  # Increase the maximum upload file size to 200MB
    client_body_timeout 60s;
    keepalive_timeout 10s;

    client_body_buffer_size 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 16k;
    proxy_buffers 4 16k;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/json application/javascript text/css;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;



    # Media server block
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name media.mydomain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://media_server:4001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /api/upload-chunk {
            proxy_pass http://media_server:4001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;  # Disable proxy buffering
            proxy_request_buffering off;  # Disable request buffering
            client_max_body_size 200M;
            client_body_timeout 120s;
            gzip off;
        }

        # Correct routing for HLS chunk uploads
        location /api/upload/hls/chunk {
            proxy_pass http://media_server:4001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;  # Disable proxy buffering
            proxy_request_buffering off;  # Disable request buffering
            client_max_body_size 200M;
            client_body_timeout 120s;
            gzip off;

        }

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name media.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/media_fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/media_privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://media_server:4001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        # Correct routing for regular chunk uploads
        location /api/upload/chunk {
            proxy_pass http://media_server:4001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;  # Disable proxy buffering
            proxy_request_buffering off;  # Disable request buffering
            client_max_body_size 200M;
            client_body_timeout 120s;
            gzip off;
        }

        # # Correct routing for HLS chunk uploads
        location /api/upload/hls/chunk {
            proxy_pass http://media_server:4001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;  # Disable proxy buffering
            proxy_request_buffering off;  # Disable request buffering
            client_max_body_size 200M;
            client_body_timeout 120s;
            gzip off;
        }

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
    }
}

Docker Configuration:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  api:
    image: ${IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - PUBLIC_API_KEY=${PUBLIC_API_KEY}
      - API_PORT=${API_PORT}
      - ALLOWED_ORIGINS=${ALLOWED_ORIGINS}
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

      - WAIT_HOSTS=db:3306
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs

  media_server:
    image: ${IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: media_server
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
      - "1935:1935"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    environment:
      - PORT=4001
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - MEDIA_ROOT=/usr/src/app/media
      - MEDIA_SERVER_URL=https://media.mydomain.com
      - GRAPHQL_API_URL=https://api.mydomain.com/graphql
      - ALLOWED_ORIGINS=${ALLOWED_ORIGINS}

    volumes:
      - media_data:/usr/src/app/media

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/certbot:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    depends_on:
      - api
      - media_server

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes:
  db_data:
  media_data:

Network Configuration:

Average Ping Time: ~276 ms from client to server
No packet loss observed

Issue:
When uploading a 5 MB chunk, the request takes about 1.5 minutes to
complete. Here are some specific observations:

Resource Usage: CPU usage stays around 2%, and memory usage is around    700 MB out of 7.5 GB available.
Disk I/O: Monitored using iotop, with no significant spikes in disk usage during the upload process.
Latency: Consistently high (~276 ms) as observed from client to server.

Steps I've Taken:
Nginx Configuration Tweaks:

Disabled buffering and request buffering for upload routes.
Set appropriate timeouts and buffer sizes.

Network Testing:

Confirmed average latency of ~276 ms.
No packet loss.

Monitoring with Tools:

Used htop, to monitor CPU, memory, and disk I/O, all
of which are well within acceptable limits during uploads.


Backend Optimization:

Implemented parallel uploads and larger chunk sizes, but still
experiencing delays.

What Could Be the Issue?
Given that my server's resources are underutilized and the disk I/O seems fine, I suspect the issue might be related to network latency or some misconfiguration in Nginx or the Node.js backend.
Questions:

Could the high latency (~276 ms) be the main cause of the slow
upload times? If so, how can I mitigate this issue?
Are there any specific Nginx or Node.js settings that I should adjust to handle
such latency better?
Could there be another bottleneck that I'm overlooking, despite low CPU, memory, and disk usage? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm at my wits' end trying to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Node Express Backend
app.js
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import firebaseAuthMiddleware from "./middleware/firebaseAuthMiddleware.js";
import cors from 'cors';
import uploadRoute from './routes/uploadRouter.js';
import uploadChunkRoute from './routes/uploadChunkRouter.js'
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { serverAdapter } from './config/bullBoard.js';

config();  // Load environment variables

const ALLOWED_ORIGINS = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS?.split(",") || [];

const app: Application = express();

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      if (!origin || ALLOWED_ORIGINS.includes(origin)) {
        return callback(null, true);
      }
      const errMsg = "The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified origin.";
      console.error(errMsg);  // Log the error message
      return callback(new Error(errMsg), false);
    },
    credentials: true, // Allow credentials if necessary
  })
);

// Increase payload size limit
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));  // Adjust the size as per your requirements
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));  // Adjust the size as per your requirements

app.use('/admin/queues', serverAdapter.getRouter());
app.use('/media', express.static(process.env.MEDIA_ROOT || './media'));

// app.use(firebaseAuthMiddleware);
app.use('/api', uploadRoute);
app.use('/api', uploadChunkRoute);

export default app;

uploadRouter.ts
import { Router, Response } from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import fs, { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';
import { hlsQueue } from '../queues/hlsQueue.js';
import { Request } from '../middleware/firebaseAuthMiddleware.js';
import logger from '../logger/index.js';

const router = Router();
// Function to sanitize file names
const sanitizeFilename = (filename: string) => {
    return filename.replace(/[^a-z0-9_\-\.]/gi, '_').toLowerCase();
};

const CHUNKS_DIR = path.join(process.env.MEDIA_ROOT || 'media', 'chunks');

if (!fs.existsSync(CHUNKS_DIR)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(CHUNKS_DIR, { recursive: true });
    logger.info(`Created chunks directory: ${CHUNKS_DIR}`);
}

// Storage configuration for chunk uploads
const chunkStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, CHUNKS_DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
});

const chunkUpload = multer({
    storage: chunkStorage,
    limits: { fileSize: 200 * 1024 * 1024 } // Limit file size to 00MB per chunk
});

// Helper function to assemble chunks
const assembleChunks = async (fileName: string, totalChunks: number, destinationDir: string): Promise<string> => {
    // Ensure the destination directory exists
    if (!fs.existsSync(destinationDir)) {
        await fsPromises.mkdir(destinationDir, { recursive: true });
        logger.info(`Created directory: ${destinationDir}`);
    }

    const finalFilePath = path.join(destinationDir, fileName);
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(finalFilePath);
    writer.setMaxListeners(0); // Remove listener limit to prevent warnings

    try {
        const chunkPromises = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= totalChunks; i++) {
            const chunkPath = path.join(CHUNKS_DIR, `${fileName}-${i}`);

            if (!fs.existsSync(chunkPath)) {
                throw new Error(`Chunk ${i} is missing`);
            }

            chunkPromises.push(
                new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
                    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(chunkPath);

                    readStream.on('error', (err) => {
                        logger.error(`Error reading chunk ${i}: ${err.message}`);
                        reject(err);
                    });

                    writer.on('error', (err) => {
                        logger.error(`Error writing to file: ${err.message}`);
                        reject(err);
                    });

                    readStream.on('end', () => {
                        logger.info(`Finished reading chunk ${i}`);
                        resolve();
                    });

                    readStream.pipe(writer, { end: false });
                }).then(() => {
                    fs.unlinkSync(chunkPath);
                    logger.info(`Deleted chunk: ${chunkPath}`);
                }).catch(err => {
                    logger.error(`Error processing chunk ${i}: ${err.message}`);
                    throw err;
                })
            );
        }

        await Promise.all(chunkPromises);
    } catch (error) {
        writer.close();
        logger.error(`Error assembling file: ${(error as Error).message}`);
        throw error;
    }

    writer.end();
    logger.info(`Finished assembling file: ${finalFilePath}`);
    return finalFilePath;
};

// Middleware to validate uploaded files
const validateUpload = (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
    }
    next();
};

// Endpoint for general media file chunk upload
router.post('/upload/chunk', chunkUpload.single('file'), validateUpload, async (req, res) => {
    const { currentChunk, totalChunks, fileName, folderName } = req.body;

    // logger.info(`Chunk Index: ${currentChunk}, Total Chunks: ${totalChunks}`);

    const tempFileName = req.file!.filename;
    const chunkFilename = `${fileName}-${currentChunk}`;
    const chunkPath = path.join(CHUNKS_DIR, chunkFilename);

    try {
        await fsPromises.rename(path.join(CHUNKS_DIR, tempFileName), chunkPath);

        if (parseInt(currentChunk, 10) === parseInt(totalChunks, 10)) {
            const destinationDir = path.join(process.env.MEDIA_ROOT || 'media', folderName || 'general');
            await assembleChunks(fileName, totalChunks, destinationDir);
            const fileUrl = `${process.env.MEDIA_SERVER_URL}/media/${folderName || 'general'}/${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;
            return res.status(200).json({ fileUrl, message: 'File uploaded and assembled successfully.', finalChunk: true });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: `Chunk ${parseInt(currentChunk)}/${totalChunks} uploaded successfully.`, finalChunk: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error during chunk processing:', (error as Error).message);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error during chunk processing', error: (error as Error).message });
    }
});

// Endpoint for HLS chunk upload
router.post('/upload/hls/chunk', chunkUpload.single('file'), validateUpload, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { artistId, albumId, songId, currentChunk, totalChunks, fileName } = req.body;

    logger.info(`Chunk Index: ${currentChunk}, Total Chunks: ${totalChunks}`);

    const tempFileName = req.file!.filename;
    const chunkFilename = `${fileName}-${currentChunk}`;
    const chunkPath = path.join(CHUNKS_DIR, chunkFilename);

    try {
        await fsPromises.rename(path.join(CHUNKS_DIR, tempFileName), chunkPath);

        if (parseInt(currentChunk, 10) === parseInt(totalChunks, 10)) {
            const destinationDir = path.join(process.env.MEDIA_ROOT || 'media', 'hls', artistId, albumId, songId);

            await assembleChunks(fileName, totalChunks, destinationDir);
            const fileUrl = `${process.env.MEDIA_SERVER_URL}/media/hls/${artistId}/${albumId}/${songId}/${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;
            const hlsUrl = `${process.env.MEDIA_SERVER_URL}/media/hls/${artistId}/${albumId}/${songId}/playlist.m3u8`;

            return res.status(200).json({ fileUrl, hlsUrl, message: 'File uploaded and assembled successfully.', finalChunk: true });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: `Chunk ${parseInt(currentChunk)}/${totalChunks} uploaded successfully.`, finalChunk: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error during chunk processing:', (error as Error).message);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error during chunk processing', error: (error as Error).message });
    }
});

router.post('/queue/transcode', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const { artistId, albumId, songId, fileName } = req.body;

        if (!artistId || !albumId || !songId || !fileName) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Missing required fields: artistId, albumId, songId, or fileName.',
            });
        }

        const destinationDir = path.join(process.env.MEDIA_ROOT || 'media', 'hls', artistId, albumId, songId);
        const hlsFilePath = path.join(destinationDir, encodeURIComponent(fileName));

        // Queue the transcoding job
        await hlsQueue.add({
            filePath: hlsFilePath,
            outputDir: destinationDir,
            artistId,
            albumId,
            songId,
            token: req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1],
        });

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Transcoding job queued successfully.',
            artistId,
            albumId,
            songId,
            fileName,
            queuedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error queuing transcoding job:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Failed to queue transcoding job.',
            error: (error as Error).message,
        });
    }
});

export default router;

FrontEnd React
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Box, Typography, IconButton, LinearProgress } from '@mui/material';
import CloudUploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CloudUpload';
import { UploadResponse } from 'app/types';
import { getFirebaseToken } from '../auth/services/firebase/firebaseAuthUtils';

interface FileUploadBoxProps {
    onFileChange: (file: File | undefined, fileUrl: string | null) => void;
    className?: string;
    currentUrl?: string;
    helperText?: string;
    supportedFormats: string[];
    folderName?: string;
}

function FileUploadBox({
    onFileChange,
    className,
    currentUrl,
    helperText,
    supportedFormats,
    folderName = 'generals'
}: FileUploadBoxProps) {
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
    const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);
    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [internalHelperText, setInternalHelperText] = useState<string | undefined>(helperText);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentUrl) {
            setFileName(decodeURIComponent(currentUrl).split('/').pop());
        }
    }, [currentUrl]);

    const handleFileUpload = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const file: File | undefined = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : undefined;

        if (file) {
            setFileName(file.name);
            setIsUploading(true);
            try {
                const { fileUrl } = await uploadFileInChunks(file);
                // setIsUploading(false);
                onFileChange(file, fileUrl); // Pass the file URL and HLS URL to the parent component
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Upload failed:', error);
                setIsUploading(false);
                onFileChange(undefined, null); // Clear the file if the upload failed
                setInternalHelperText('File upload failed. Please try again.'); // Set an error message
                setError(true); // Set the error flag
            }
        } else {
            setFileName(undefined);
            onFileChange(undefined, null); // Handle the case when no file is selected
        }
    };

    const uploadFileInChunks = async (file: File): Promise<{ fileUrl: string }> => {
        const chunkSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
        const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
        let uploadedBytes = 0;
        let lastResponse: UploadResponse | null = null;
        let startByte = 0;

        const uploadUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_MEDIA_API_URL}/upload/chunk`;

        for (let chunkIndex = 1; chunkIndex <= totalChunks; chunkIndex++) {
            const endByte = Math.min(startByte + chunkSize, file.size);
            const chunk = file.slice(startByte, endByte);

            // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
            lastResponse = await uploadChunkAndHandleResponse(
                chunk,
                totalChunks,
                chunkIndex, // chunkIndex + 1 to ensure the server receives a 1-based index
                uploadUrl,
                file.name,
                folderName
            );
            startByte = endByte;

            uploadedBytes += chunk.size;
            const newProgress = parseFloat(((uploadedBytes / file.size) * 100).toFixed(2)); // Round to 2 decimal places
            setUploadProgress(Math.min(newProgress, 100));
        }

        setUploadProgress(100); // Ensure progress is set to 100% after all chunks are done

        if (!lastResponse) {
            throw new Error('No response received from the server.');
        }

        // Return only fileUrl if isHls is false
        return {
            fileUrl: lastResponse.fileUrl
        };
    };

    const uploadChunkAndHandleResponse = async (
        chunk: Blob,
        totalChunks: number,
        currentChunk: number,
        uploadUrl: string,
        fileName: string,
        folderName: string
    ): Promise<UploadResponse> => {
        // Get the Firebase token
        const token = await getFirebaseToken();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', chunk);
        formData.append('totalChunks', totalChunks.toString());
        formData.append('currentChunk', currentChunk.toString());
        formData.append('fileName', fileName);
        formData.append('folderName', folderName);

        const response = await fetch(uploadUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` // Add the Authorization header
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = (await response.json()) as UploadResponse;
            console.error(`Chunk upload ${currentChunk} failed:`, errorData.message);
            throw new Error(`Chunk upload ${currentChunk} failed: ${errorData.message}`);
        }

        return (await response.json()) as UploadResponse;
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Box
                className={className}
                sx={{
                    border: `2px dashed ${error ? 'red' : '#ccc'}`,
                    borderRadius: '8px',
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    padding: '20px',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    '&:hover': {
                        borderColor: '#888'
                    },
                    width: '100%',
                    margin: '0 auto'
                }}
                onClick={() => document.getElementById('file-upload')?.click()}
            >
                <input
                    type="file"
                    id="file-upload"
                    style={{ display: 'none' }}
                    onChange={handleFileUpload}
                    accept={supportedFormats.join(',')}
                />
                <IconButton color="primary">
                    <CloudUploadIcon fontSize="large" />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography
                    variant="body1"
                    color="textSecondary"
                >
                    Browse file to upload
                </Typography>
                {fileName && (
                    <Typography
                        variant="body2"
                        color="textPrimary"
                        sx={{ marginTop: '10px' }}
                    >
                        {fileName}
                    </Typography>
                )}
            </Box>
            {isUploading && (
                <Box sx={{ width: '100%', marginTop: '10px' }}>
                    <LinearProgress
                        variant="determinate"
                        value={uploadProgress}
                    />
                    <Typography
                        variant="body2"
                        color="textSecondary"
                    >
                        {uploadProgress}% uploaded
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
            {internalHelperText && (
                <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    color={error ? 'red' : 'textSecondary'}
                    sx={{ marginTop: '10px' }}
                >
                    {internalHelperText}
                </Typography>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default FileUploadBox;

